# vlc - not playing back opus file created by the demo in the opus lib

Tags: audio, ubuntu-12.04, media, opus

on ubuntu 12.04 did an apt update / upgrade and only got to vlc 2.0.3

```
rob@ ~$ cvlc -v
VLC media player 2.0.3 Twoflower (revision 2.0.2-93-g77aa89e)
[0x1f47108] main libvlc warning: This doesn't look like a valid plugins cache
[0x1f7e758] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
```

It throws all kinds of errors playing back an opus file created with the opus lib 1.1.1 ...

```
[0x1ecd108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7faddcc115a0] Header missing


rob@ opus$ ./opus_demo -e voip 48000 1 120000  /home/rob/133041.wav ../myopus.opus

libopus 1.1.1-beta
Encoding 48000 Hz input at 120.000 kb/s in auto mode with 960-sample frames.
average bitrate:             147.403 kb/s
maximum bitrate:             240.400 kb/s
active bitrate:              154.607 kb/s
bitrate standard deviation:   42.169 kb/s
```

'myopus.opus' wont playback on the vlc UI client ( 2.0.8)

i can select the file from the directory viewer and hit play but nothing happens.

Not sure how to playback the test files being created with the opus demo ??

Answer (score 2):

To produce `.opus` files, which can be played with VLC, use [`opusenc`](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus-tools/ws/man/opusenc.html) from the [opus-tools](http://opus-codec.org/downloads/) package, or [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) or [avconv](https://libav.org/).

`opus_demo` is a simple demonstration program used to test the codec, without requiring additional dependencies.  The files produced by `opus_demo -e` are intended for use with `opus_demo -d`.